# Omniauth / Rails Issue - Can't start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I'm trying to follow along with Railscasts #235 (Omniauth in a rails app).

Having some trouble with the Omniauth gem in Rails (v3.2). When I install the gem in my Gemfile, and specify the following in omniauth.rb (in config/initializers/):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, '...', '...'
end
```

I can't seem to start my server - I get the following error:

```
/Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:38:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :twitter. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-twitter). (LoadError)
```

I could include the omniauth-twitter gem (the server starts with that), but I don't know why this wouldn't work without it. **When I forked the repo for the railscast, everything worked fine**, so not sure why this is happening. I thought it was because I have the omniauth-twitter gem installed (although not being used in the bundle), and I uninstalled it but that didn't work.

Full Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'redcarpet'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'annotate'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Full stack trace below:

```
/Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:38:in `rescue in provider': Could not find matching strategy for :twitter. You may need to install an additional gem (such as omniauth-twitter). (LoadError)
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:35:in `provider'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/omniauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:7:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `new'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `block in build'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `each'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `inject'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:113:in `build'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:470:in `app'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:31:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/Development/rails/workbench/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/tarunsachdeva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read error message. You need add `omniauth-twitter` gem to `Gemfile`.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear with my question: I could include the omniauth-twitter gem (the server starts with that), but I don't know why this wouldn't work without it. When I forked the repo for the railscast, everything worked fine (the railscasts only uses the omniauth gem), so not sure why this is happening. I thought it was because I have the omniauth-twitter gem installed previously in another app (although not being used in the bundle), and I uninstalled it but that didn't work.

Comment: Why are you have initializers in `lib` folder?

Comment: Whoops, Typo. Initializers are in config, fixed.

Comment: Maybe another RoR version cause it?

Comment: Not sure, going to leave the Omniauth-twitter gem in. Seems like that's the only solution for now. THanks.

Comment: Omniauth was extracted into various gems for each integration point (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Identity).  He mentions it in a later Railscast

Answer (score 0):

I'm fashionably late to the party here but I think you were being asked for omniauth-twitter because you were using the latest version of Omniauth > 1 and not the ~> 0.3.0 version as in the Railscasts.

But you've probably already figured that out ;)